# Ubuntu not shutting down ( going to black screen ) 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, live-usb, persistence

I am currently using a USB persistent install of Ubuntu. Its a simple 4GB drive with a 2.8GB partition (casper-rw storage partition). I setup an administrator account and set it to login automatically. I also removed `ubiquity` to simply use this as a go anywhere install.

Heres my issue:

I'm logged in as my account, and I click the top right gear and select "Shut Down". Text pops up showing its quitting processes.. etc. and then goes to the plymouth animation. But...  The screen goes black, and then it goes to the login screen. Now when I'm at the login screen, I go into terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and don't you know, I'm logged in as Ubuntu.

So then I try the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo shutdown now
```

It goes to the plymouth screen again as if its shutting down, AND the screen goes black once again but the computer has not turned off, as in the USB is still flashing the light, the fans are still on, the only thing off is the screen.

Is this a bug? If not maybe I did something wrong? Perhaps its that I made an account but... if there is a work around for this please let me know.

Comment: Try sudo telinit 0 and see if you get anything different.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the GRUB configuration file (run in terminal `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`).

Add to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` one of the following parameters:

```
acpi=force, acpi=on, nomodeset, noapic, acpi=off
```

For example, the new line might read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

Save the file, quit the text editor, and run this command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```